# How to post and upload content via email?

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache

I have a website and I want to be able to post things through my email, just like in many big social networks. (like Facebook, Flickr)

Like: I would send a message to 'post@domain.com'
the title would be saved to a MySQL db and attachment is saved to a directory.
or something similar to this.
I'm more focused on the attachment,but I'll take anything that will get me started

I heard that it is possible through a "Cron Job", but I'm not familiar with how that works. So please link to a tutorial or some code that I can learn from.

-Thank you

Comment: What's with the dislikes.. at least leave comments

Comment: comment: unclear, too broad, no  effort shown

Comment: Cron job is just a simple php function. but you have to setup this on your serve. Where server triggers this function again & again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a bigger and more complex system than a simple tutorial.

Conceptually, you'd have a mail exchanger that would accept incoming mail and store it somewhere. Then, you'd have a separate system that would connect to the mail exchanger (through POP, IMAP or filesystem) and get the mails since its last run. It would then parse the mail and run whatever action you specified.